# Allow few domains to Iframe my content

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I want to prevent other websites from IFraming my website content onto their websites, but at the same time I want to allow few websites to do so. anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you are limited when in an iframe due to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

will edit in break out keep in code on moment.

```
if (window=window.top) {    
}else {
top.location.href = 'http://YourDomain.com';
}
```

---

keep in iframe example for canvas pages. i use this for keeping my page in canvas on facebook.

```
if (window!=window.top) { 
}else {
top.location.href = 'https://apps.facebook.com/AnotherFeed/?ref=redirect#comments';
}
```

---

possible work around research. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-document_messaging

question from https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/284446968265491/ refered to stack by me.